# Please while do i always get this error for every single action i take in jenkins : 403 MESSAGE: No valid crumb was included in the request SERVLET:

Tags: jenkins, pipeline, cicd

HTTP ERROR 403 No valid crumb was included in the request
URI:    /manage/pluginManager/install
STATUS: 403
MESSAGE:    No valid crumb was included in the request
SERVLET:    Stapler

every action i take in my jenkins leads me to the error